# HYPERLEDGER : Error While Starting Business Network

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I am researching on Hyperledger. After going through the basic tutorials and documentation, I have started setting up a Blockchain Business Network With Hyperledger Fabric & Composer Running on Multiple Physical Machine as described on https://www.skcript.com/svr/setting-up-a-blockchain-business-network-with-hyperledger-fabric-and-composer-running-in-multiple-physical-machine/.

I am already done with setting up the Hyperledger environment. We are able to create business network archives (.bna) and business cards (.card) as well. But while I try to start the created business network (using composer network deploy and composer network start commands on Ubuntu CLI) the CLI responds with an error saying,

> composer network start --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret
>   adminpw --card admin@admin_conn --file admin.card -a
>   basic-sample-network.bna Starting business network from archive:
>   basic-sample-network.bna Business network definition:
>           Identifier: basic-sample-network@0.2.0-20180102082548
>           Description: The Hello World of Hyperledger Composer samples
>
> Processing these Network Admins:
>           userName: admin
>
> Starting business network definition. This may take a minute... Error:
>   Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: No valid
>   responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an
>   error: Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot get
>   package for the chaincode to be instantiated
>   (basic-sample-network:0.16.6)-open
>   /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/basic-sample-network.0.16.6: no
>   such file or directory)

And on the playground UI,

[image]

It would be great if any of you could guide me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** :

Version of Composer : v0.19.0

Worked Out Link : https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/business-network/bnd-deploy

This is where I got stucked now.

*composer network install* command worked fine. But *network start* command is not working fine.

> user1@peer2:~/fabric-tools/rosternetwork$ composer network start --networkName rosternetwork --networkVersion 1.0.0 --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin -S adminpw
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chain code error (status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode (rosternetwork:1.0.0))
>   Command failed
>   Starting business network rosternetwork at version 1.0.0
>
> Processing these Network Admins:
>         userName: admin
>
> Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
>   Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode (rosternetwork:1.0.0))
>   Command failed

Searched with the error message, but didn't found any solution.

Comment: this is a custom tutorial, that relies on Fabric v1.0.4 looks like (unless its been updated - if not, means  you would need to use a Composer version like 0.16.5 to be installed (@0.16.5) - you didn't post your Composer version . if you've installed composer v0.19.0, this might be a reason why its not working - you would need a `composer network install` first (before `composer network start`)  for the business network in question - see examples of the sequence here using 0.19.x -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony : Thanks for the reply.. I will try the multi org link you provided and will let know my feedback.